# How to stop a corda node running a example cordapp?

Tags: corda

I have cloned a cordapp example https://github.com/corda/samples/tree/release-V4/cordapp-example

cd /cordapp-example
./gradlew deployNodes
kotlin-source/build/nodes/runnodes

The example runs correctly.

How do is shutdown the example cordapp and corda node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the above example , update the gradle file to include sshd option as **sshdPort** , this generates sshd config in node.conf for each node.

```
sshd {
    port=2222
}
```

Reference - https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/generating-a-node.html

From your local desktop Login via ssh into Remote Ubuntu machine

```
ssh -p <port> <ipaddress> -l user1
```

Reference - https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/shell.html#the-shell-via-the-local-terminal

And type in run command in corda Crash shell launched

```
run gracefulShutdown
```

Reference - https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/shell.html#shutting-down-the-node

This shuts down the corda node in the remote ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 0):

Type `bye` inside each node terminal.

Comment: I am having access to remote ubuntu lab machine where the corda terminal never shows up for me to type in bye. It runs in background i guess. What is the recommended way to stop a server?

Comment: Usually a Corda node is deployed as a system service that starts on Ubuntu machine startup. You can stop the service (i.e. stop the node) by opening a terminal in your remote Ubnutu machine and typing `sudo stop corda`. More details on deploying a node to a server can be found [here](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/deploying-a-node.html).

Comment: I have run it using gradle and as per documentation examples. Its in dev mode and hence not system service.

Comment: Spent over few hours and not yet found where to look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61718661/how-to-access-corda-crash-shell-on-remote-ubuntu-terminal-run-of-corda-example