# How to access corda crash shell on remote ubuntu terminal run of corda example?

Tags: corda

I am able to set up sample from https://github.com/corda/samples/tree/release-V4/cordapp-example

As per instructions on https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/tutorial-cordapp.html#running-nodes-across-machines

However, i never come across in documentation how to access the CORDA Crash shell in ubuntu to type in Corda interactive shell to execute the following !
Creating an IOU via the interactive shell #
We can create a new IOU using the ExampleFlow$Initiator flow. For example, from the interactive shell of PartyA, you can agree an IOU of 50 with PartyB by running flow start ExampleFlow$Initiator iouValue: 50, otherParty: "O=PartyB,L=New York,C=US".

Can anybody clarify how to launch access to Corda interactive shell when on remote ubuntu machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the shell in one of 2 ways:

1. Via [ssh](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/shell.html#the-shell-via-ssh)
2. Via [standalone shell](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/shell.html#the-standalone-shell)

Comment: I had to add the sshd { port = 2222 } in build.xml and ensure same gets generated into  workflows-java/build/nodes/PartyA_node.conf and  workflows-java/build/nodes/PartyA/nodes.conf

Comment: You can edit the `node.conf` manually; you don't have to rebuild every time, unless you're changing code.